# Why getSum does not get inlined by hotspot jvm?

Tags: java, jit, jvm-hotspot, escape-analysis

Here's the example I tried to reproduce from [**Java Performance: The Definitive Guide, Page 97**](https://books.google.com/books?id=aIhUAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA97#v=onepage&q&f=false) on the topic of *Escape Analysis*. This is probably what should happen:

1. `getSum()` must get hot enough and with appropriate JVM parameters it must be inlined into the caller `main()`.
2. As both `list` and `sum` variables do not escape from `main()` method they could be marked as `NoEscape` hence JVM could use stack-allocation for them instead of heap-allocation.

But I ran it through [jitwatch](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch/) and the result showed that `getSum()` compiles into native-assembly and doesn't get inlined into `main()`. Not to mention consequently stack-allocation didn't happen either.

What am I doing wrong in here ? (I have put the whole code and hotspot log [here](https://github.com/nimatrueway/jit-hotspot-analysis-sample).)

Here's the code:

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class EscapeAnalysisTest {

    private static class Sum {

        private BigInteger sum;
        private int n;

        Sum(int n) {
            this.n = n;
        }

        synchronized final BigInteger getSum() {
            if (sum == null) {
                sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
                }
            }
            return sum;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            Sum sum = new Sum(i);
            list.add(sum.getSum());
        }
        System.out.println(list.get(list.size() - 1));
    }

}
```

JVM parameters I used:

```bash
-server
-verbose:gc
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:+TraceClassLoading
-XX:MaxInlineSize=60
-XX:+PrintAssembly
-XX:+LogCompilation
```

Comment: The `synchronized` may be a reason.

Comment: @Henry I tried to copy from the book, nevertheless I also tried without synchronized and still couldn't have it inlined.

Comment: intersting, but I see an entry like this in your logs `task_queued compile_id='37' compile_kind='osr'`, seems like `osr` *is* kicked in

Comment: yes @Eugene, getSum method gets compiled into native assembly. but I was expecting something else (I described in the question)

Comment: Your loop is running in the `main` method, so it can only switch to an optimized version via OSR. This is known to have limitations.

Comment: @Holger i was leaving this one to answer "later today"... :) too late I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to know why something is inlined or not, you can look in the compilation log for the `inline_success` and `inline_fail` tags.

However to even get something inlined, the caller would have to be compiled, in your case you want an inline in the `main` method so the only way this is going to happen is on-stack replacement (OSR). Looking at your log, you can see a few OSR compilations but none of the `main` method: there is simply not enough work in your `main` method.

You can fix that by increasing the number of iteration of your `for` loop. By increasing it to `100_000`, I got a first OSR compilation.

For such a small example is looked at `-XX:+PrintCompilation -XX:+PrintInlining` rather than the whole `LogCompilation` output and I saw:

```
@ 27   EscapeAnalysisTest$Sum::getSum (51 bytes)   inlining prohibited by policy
```

That's not very helpful... but looking a bit a HotSpot source code reveals that it's probably because of a policy that prevents C1 compilations to inline methods that have been OSR compiled by C2.
In any case, looking at the inlining done by the C1 compilation is not that interesting.

Adding more loop iterations (`1_000_000` with a modulo on the argument to `Sum` to reduce run time) gets us a C2 OSR of `main` with:

```
@31   EscapeAnalysisTest$Sum::getSum (51 bytes)   already compiled into a big method
```

That part of C2's policy is rather self-descriptive and is controlled by the `InlineSmallCode` flag: `-XX:InlineSmallCode=4k` tells HotSpot that the threshold for "big method" is at 4kB of native code. On my machine that was enough to get `getSum` inlined:

```
  14206   45 %     4       EscapeAnalysisTest::main @ 10 (61 bytes)
                              @ 25   EscapeAnalysisTest$Sum::<init> (10 bytes)   inline (hot)
                                @ 1   java.lang.Object::<init> (1 bytes)   inline (hot)
              s               @ 31   EscapeAnalysisTest$Sum::getSum (51 bytes)   inline (hot)
                                @ 31   java.math.BigInteger::valueOf (62 bytes)   inline (hot)
                                  @ 58   java.math.BigInteger::<init> (77 bytes)   inline (hot)
                                    @ 1   java.lang.Number::<init> (5 bytes)   inline (hot)
                                      @ 1   java.lang.Object::<init> (1 bytes)   inline (hot)
                                @ 34   java.math.BigInteger::add (123 bytes)   inline (hot)
                                  @ 41   java.math.BigInteger::add (215 bytes)   inline (hot)
                                  @ 48   java.math.BigInteger::<init> (38 bytes)   inline (hot)
                                    @ 1   java.lang.Number::<init> (5 bytes)   inline (hot)
                                      @ 1   java.lang.Object::<init> (1 bytes)   inline (hot)
                              @ 34   java.util.ArrayList::add (29 bytes)   inline (hot)
                                @ 7   java.util.ArrayList::ensureCapacityInternal (13 bytes)   inline (hot)
                                  @ 6   java.util.ArrayList::calculateCapacity (16 bytes)   inline (hot)
                                  @ 9   java.util.ArrayList::ensureExplicitCapacity (26 bytes)   inline (hot)
                                    @ 22   java.util.ArrayList::grow (45 bytes)   too big
```

(Note that i never had to use `MaxInlineSize`)

For reference here's the modified loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
  Sum sum = new Sum(i % 10_000);
  list.add(sum.getSum());
}
```

Comment: this one is interesting: `inlining prohibited by policy` I've seen the sources, so if JIT knows that `C2` will use `OSR` it will not even inline it in `C1`, since there is no sense probably. I see this as yet another form of "made not entrant" in 3-td Tier, when the 4-th has already compiled this method into something "better"